# How to use and plot only a part of a colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have multiple curves that differ in one parameter and which I want to plot in one figure. To distinguish them, I want to use one of matplotlib's colorbars. To do so I produce a list of colors depending on said parameter. Additionally, I want to add a colorbar to explain the colors that are used. I can easily do all of that. The problem is now, that I want to use only a part of the available colormap, as it gets too bright and thus barely visible above some threshold. But when I now choose the colors only in a subrange, I did not find a way to adjust the range of the displayed colorbar.

Here is a (nearly) minimal example of what I want to achieve:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1,
                       height_ratios=[1, 4]
                       )
ax = [plt.subplot(g) for g in gs]

parameterToColorBy = np.linspace(5, 10, 6, dtype=float)

maxColor = 0.85
colors = [plt.get_cmap("inferno")(i)
          for i in np.linspace(0, maxColor, parameterToColorBy.shape[0])]

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(parameterToColorBy[0],
                            parameterToColorBy[0]+
                            (parameterToColorBy[-1]-parameterToColorBy[0])/
                            maxColor)
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax[0],
                               cmap="inferno",
                               norm=norm,
                               ticks=parameterToColorBy,
                               orientation='horizontal')
ax[0].xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

for p, c in zip(parameterToColorBy, colors):
    ax[1].plot(np.arange(2)/p, c=c)

plt.show()
```

The result looks at follows:

[image: starting point]

I now want the colorbar to stop at 10. But if I just adjust the `xlim` of the subplot by adding the line `ax[0].set_xlim(0, maxColor)`, the colored part is adjusted correctly, but the surrounding box is messed up:

[image: Result of set_xlim]

Alternatively, I found a function for colorbars `set_clim`. But this only changes the normalization and does not seem to work as I want. Adding `cb.set_clim(parameterToColorBy[0], parameterToColorBy[-1])` results in an changed colors but unchanged axis:

[image: Result of set_xlim]

What I seem to need is either an appropriate way to adjust the limits of the displayed colorbar, or a way to create an own colorbar as a subset of an available colorbar. Is there any way to achieve one of these things?

Comment: Could you use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105100/189050, only restricting the linspace at the other end instead (e.g., 0.0-0.9)?

Comment: @Deditos Thanks for the suggestion. I could probably do something along those lines by just using a lot of points and get some form of a roughly continuous colormap. But I think I prefer the solution suggested by tom in his answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can truncate the colormap by using the `truncate_colormap` function I have written in the code below. It creates a new `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap` from an existing colormap.

Note that you then don't need to scale the `Normalise` instance by `maxColor`, and you need to use this new colormap instance when creating your `colors` list and the `colorbar`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1,
                       height_ratios=[1, 4]
                       )
ax = [plt.subplot(g) for g in gs]

parameterToColorBy = np.linspace(5, 10, 6, dtype=float)

def truncate_colormap(cmap, minval=0.0, maxval=1.0, n=-1):
    if n == -1:
        n = cmap.N
    new_cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
         'trunc({name},{a:.2f},{b:.2f})'.format(name=cmap.name, a=minval, b=maxval),
         cmap(np.linspace(minval, maxval, n)))
    return new_cmap

minColor = 0.00
maxColor = 0.85
inferno_t = truncate_colormap(plt.get_cmap("inferno"), minColor, maxColor)

colors = [inferno_t(i)
          for i in np.linspace(0, 1, parameterToColorBy.shape[0])]

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(parameterToColorBy[0],
                            parameterToColorBy[-1])

cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax[0],
                               cmap=inferno_t,
                               norm=norm,
                               ticks=parameterToColorBy,
                               orientation='horizontal')

ax[0].xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

for p, c in zip(parameterToColorBy, colors):
    ax[1].plot(np.arange(2)/p, c=c)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using the truncated color map with ep.draw_legend from the `Earthpy` project but I got an error: `ValueError: Colormap trunc(Greys,0.20,0.80) is not recognized.`